# What is wrong with this product of measures in the $m\to \infty$ limit?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, wiener-measure

This question is about a passage in Reed & Simon concerning the Wiener measure and path integrals. To give the context, the authors consider the Trotter product formula

$$e^{-t(H_0+V)}f=\lim_{m\to \infty}(e^{-(t/m)H_0}e^{-(t/m)V})^mf$$

Where

$$(e^{-(t/m)H_0}e^{-(t/m)V})^mf=\int\cdots \int p\left(x_0,x_1;\frac{t}{m}\right)e^{-(t/m)V(x_1)}\cdots p\left(x_{m-1},x_m;\frac{t}{m}\right)e^{-(t/m)V(x_m)}f(x_m) dx_1\cdots dx_m\tag{X.119}$$

Where $p(x,y;t)$ is defined by $$p(x,y;t)=(4\pi t)^{-d/2}e^{-|x-y|^2/4t}$$

The authors then say:

> There are two problems in trying to take $m$ to infinity in the right hand side of (X.119). **The first is that the infinite product of Lebesgue measures does not yield a reasonable measure**.

Now, this might be very silly and it might be a very basic thing, but why the infinite product of Lebesgue measures does not yield a reasonable measure?

What is the intuitive picture here and what is the rigorous justification?

Comment: [Infinite-dimensional Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite-dimensional_Lebesgue_measure)?

Comment: Thanks for the link. But what is the point then? Is it that if the infinite product defined a measure, it would satisfy the conditions of the theorem, and therefore it cannot exist, or it *does define a measure* but without satisfying some of the conditions of the theorem you linked?

Comment: They work around this problem by constructing the Wiener measure. My measure theory is very rusty. Maybe someone else can help.
[Google books for context.](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Kz7s7bgVe8gC&pg=PA277&lpg=PA277&dq=The+first+is+that+the+infinite+product+of+Lebesgue+measures+does+not+yield+a+reasonable+measure.&source=bl&ots=lWq15eLdiN&sig=ACfU3U3_aUlCd6eQKfYD1JlENZM6VuHOIg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiDy7KHvqviAhVRCjQIHTPBBlwQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=The%20first%20is%20that%20the%20infinite%20product%20of%20Lebesgue%20measures%20does%20not%20yield%20a%20reasonable%20measure.&f=false).